# Dropdown only returns item text/value from first item

Tags: c#, asp.net

EDIT: So I found that this line `listItem.Value = rdr["lvl"].ToString();` was adding the same value for each item in the dropdown. Since each text item had the same value, I guess it always defaulted to the first text item. I'm now passing `lvl` through another query instead of the dropdown. Thanks for all the helpful input!

I'm trying to accomplish a pretty simple task which I've done numerous times before. For some reason, I can't get my dropdown to correctly pass the `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`.

The `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue` are always returned for the first item in the dropdown, regardless of which item I select.

What am I doing wrong?

Defining dropdown and button:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" >
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Populating dropdown on PageLoad:

```
myConnection.Open();
SqlCommand rpt = new SqlCommand(getreports, myConnection);
SqlDataReader rdr = rpt.ExecuteReader();
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ListItem listItem = new ListItem();
        listItem.Text = rdr["manager"].ToString();
        listItem.Value = rdr["lvl"].ToString();
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(listItem);
    }
    rdr.Close();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Code for button click that should pass `SelectedItem` and `SelectedValue`:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        string user = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
        string lvl = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
        Label1.Text = user;
        Label2.Text = lvl;
    }
```

Comment: Where is the code that populates the dropdown being called?

Comment: The dropdown gets populated on `PageLoad`

Comment: @Camilo He did wrap it in `if (!Page.IsPostPack)`. I thought of that myself, but unless he's got another location that's doing it on PostBack that's not the issue.

Comment: @ahwm Nope, that's the only place it's being populated

Comment: The `DropDownList` isn't in an `UpdatePanel` or anything funky like that, right?

Comment: Nope, no UpdatePanels...the dropdown is sitting in the main body of the HTML and is not encapsulated by anything.

Comment: are you doing anything different with your viewstate?

Comment: @VanHalen I don't think so...I've never used viewstate before

Comment: Would moving your `myConnection.Open()` and `SqlCommand` lines inside your if block make a difference? I would expect not, but maybe the unclosed open connection on PostBack is causing an issue?

Comment: @ahwm thanks for this suggestion...I tried moving that code inside the if block and still get the same results

Comment: I'm not sure, then. I ran some tests locally but couldn't get it to duplicate the issue.

Comment: The change may not be reaching the backend... Not sure if this will help but have you tried setting AutoPostBack="true" on the DropDownList?

Comment: @Walker Yes, when I set the dropdown AutoPostBack="true", the dropdown immediately reverts back to the first item after making a selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the same value was being assigned for each item. This was the reason the first item in the dropdown kept being passed regardless of the selection. As long as the values are different, all the above code works as expected.